# Redirecting batch file echo commands to TextBox hangs on Dispatcher.Invoke call

Tags: c#, wpf, batch-file

I have a small application that has an informational text box that is suppose to output executed commands to it.

Currently I have it setup so that the `Console.Write[WriteLine]` appends correctly to the text box. That code is as follows:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // bind the console output to the new text box
        var writer = new TextBoxStreamWriter(x_OutputTextBox);
        Console.SetOut(writer);
        Console.SetError(writer);            
    }
}

internal class TextBoxStreamWriter : TextWriter
{
    static TextBox _text = null;

    public TextBoxStreamWriter(TextBox outputBox)
    {
        _text = outputBox;
    }

    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        base.Write(value);
        _text.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _text.AppendText(string.Format("{0} - {1}", DateTime.Now, value)));
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        base.WriteLine(value);
        _text.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _text.AppendText(string.Format("{0} - {1}", DateTime.Now, value + Environment.NewLine)));
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

That all works fine and dandy, but when I then try to output the echo results from a batch file I get a problem. I have looked at numerous questions/answers on the topic such as: [View Output in a Batch (.bat) file from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634700/view-output-in-a-batch-bat-file-from-c-sharp-code) but those options didn't work for me. **When the overrides for `WriteLine` or `Write` functions are called it just hangs and doesn't write anything. How can I fix that?**

My `Process` implementation works like:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.OutputDataReceived += ReadOutput;
process.ErrorDataReceived += ReadErrorOutput;
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
//process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe", @"/c " + Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "BatchFile", "test.bat"))
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "BatchFile", "test2.bat"))
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    Verb = "runas",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    //WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "BatchFile", "Information.bat"),
    WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "BatchFile") + @"\",
};

process.Start();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();

process.WaitForExit();
```

The output redirects:

```
private void ReadOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data == null)
        return;

    Console.Write(e.Data);
}

private void ReadErrorOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data == null)
        return;

    Console.Write(e.Data);
}
```

The batch file is super simple at the moment:

```
echo off
echo Finding Information
echo .......................
echo foo bar is cool
echo this day kinda sucks
echo .......................

echo All Processes Complete!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have deadlocked the UI thread.

You haven't shared a completed enough code example to know for sure the exact context of the code that executes the external process, but based on your problem description it is almost certainly found in some code running in the UI thread, e.g. a `Button` object's `Click` event handler, like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.OutputDataReceived += ReadOutput;
    process.ErrorDataReceived += ReadErrorOutput;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "BatchFile", "test2.bat"))
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        Verb = "runas",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "BatchFile") + "\\",
    };

    process.Start();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

On the other hand, when data is received, you attempt to transfer control to the UI thread (so that the `TextBox` can be safely accessed) by calling `Dispatcher.Invoke()`:

```
_text.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)
```

The `Invoke()` method can only complete if and when the UI thread is available to receive messages. But your other code is sitting there blocking the UI thread as it waits for the process to complete, preventing anything else from happening.

The most obvious fix is to just remove the call `process.WaitForExit();`. This would be appropriate if there is in fact no code remaining to execute in the method where the process is executed.

If, however, it happens that in the code you didn't share there is in fact some code that needs to execute when the process finishes, you can accomplish that still without blocking the UI thread. The most obvious way to do *that* in turn would be to add a handler for the `Process.Exited` event, which is raised (of course) when the process exits.

Of course, that code may also need to execute on the UI thread. In which case you'll need to call `Dispatcher.Invoke()` again. In fact, this would be fine, but the code does start to get a bit awkward and unwieldy at that point. Another alternative is to combine `async`/`await` with the `Exited` event to simplify how the code looks. For example:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    process.OutputDataReceived += ReadOutput;
    process.ErrorDataReceived += ReadErrorOutput;
    process.Exited += (sender, e) => tcs.SetResult(true);
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "BatchFile", "test2.bat"))
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        Verb = "runas",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "BatchFile") + "\\",
    };

    process.Start();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    bool result = await tcs.Task;

    // Do your additional post-process work here
}
```

This will effectively allow the method to pause execution and wait for the process to exit, without actually causing the *thread* itself to be blocked. The method returns at the `await` expression, and then execution of the method is resumed later when the task completes.

Comment: There is no code to be executed after the process. That is all in its own function that is called via a `RelayCommand` call from the xaml attached to a button `Command` property. Thanks for your solution, that has seemed to solved my problems.